# Generalizing CIT-groups to odd case

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

A CIT-group is a group such that the centralizer of any involution is a 2-subgroup. The structure of these groups is known from the works of Suzuki and others.

Here is my question: has the odd case also been studied?

For example, if we define a CITp-group a group such that the centralizer of any p-element is a p-subgroup, what is known about these groups?

Any reference would be highly appreciated.

P.S I asked the question in [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493190/generalizing-cit-groups-to-odd-case) a few days ago but I did not get any responses.

Comment: There was quite a lot of work on the case $p =3$ by people such as P. Ferguson, and perhaps by G. Higman and his students. Finite groups in which the centralizer of any element of order $3$ is a $3$-group were sometimes called $C\theta \theta$-groups in the literature. Also, W. Feit and J.G. Thompson in Nagoya Journal circa 1962, classified finite groups with a self centralizing Sylow $3$-subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thank you very much for your answer. Your references led me to a paper of Arad and Chillag (On Finite Groups with Conditions on the Centralizers of p-Elements, 1978) which discusses the exact same thing that I was looking for. The groups are called Cpp groups. For p=2, they are just CIT-groups and for p=3 are called Cθθ -groups.